# GWT FocusPanel setProperty("left",xx") does not work

Tags: gwt, drag

I am implementing "drag" applying "set left".

Here are my code:

```
scrollPanel.setWidget(focusPanel);//add a focusPanel to the existing scrollPanel
focusPanel.setWidget(flowPanel); //add a flowPanelto the existing focusPanel
flowPanel.add(image) // add a image to  the flowPanel
```

scrollPanel.setPixelSize(scrollPanle_width,scrollPanle_height)
focusPanel.setPixelSize(image_width, image__height)

Enlarge the image, so  image size is larger than scrollPanel size

Try to drag the image to be viewed inside scrollPanel,

(1)Working way

```
flowPanel.getElement().getStyle().setPropertyPx("left",  offset );
```

When drag, image could be moved.

(2)Not working

```
focusPanel.getElement().getStyle().setPropertyPx("left",  offset );
```

When drag, image could not be moved.
Also try this and no luck
    Widget focusPanelWidget = scrollPanel.getWidget();
    focusPanelWidget.getElement().getStyle().setPropertyPx("left",  offset );

So Any one could help to see why "set left" does not work for focusPanel?
Do appreciate any help!

Many thanks!

Comment: The `left` property depends on the `position` property, see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp). I think you should add `position: relative;`.

Comment: It works, thank you!